# timestamp to YYYYMMDD convertion in aggregation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, date, timestamp, aggregation-framework

throws error message 
assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$dateToString is only defined on year 0-9999, tried to use year 292278994",
    "code" : 18537
} : aggregate failed

for timestamp "1481045214411"

> db.collection.aggregate(
>    [
>     {
>       $group:{
>                _id : "$department",
>                startTimeX : { $min:{$dateToString: {format:"%Y%m%d",date: new Date("$date")}} }
>       }
>     }
>    ]
>   )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a Date from milisecond timestamp directly, but a simple trick can help you achieve this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group:{
         _id:"$department",
         startTimeX:{
            $min:{
               $dateToString:{
                  format:"%Y%m%d",
                  date:{
                     $add:[
                        new Date(0),
                        "$date"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```